# uninitialized constant Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem with routes...

**routes.rb**

```
resources :documents do

  resources :user do
     delete 'user_unassign'
  end

  resources :attachments do    
    collection do
      get :index_parent_attachments
    end
  end

end

resources :document_types do
   resources :documents
end



devise_scope :user do
     #    root :to => "devise/sessions#new" #, :as => :root
 end

       devise_for :users 

 namespace :admin do
   resources :users, :document_types
 end
```

When I click on this link:

```
<%= link_to 'unfollow', document_user_user_unassign_path(document, user.id), :method => 'delete' %>
```

it follow this route localhost:3000/documents/1/user/2/user_unassign and i get an error: uninitialized constant UserController

**Routes**

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                            Controller#Action
                                         root GET    /                                                                      profiles#dashboard
                                    user_root GET    /profiles/dashboard(.:format)                                          profiles#dashboard
                  document_user_user_unassign DELETE /documents/:document_id/user/:user_id/user_unassign(.:format)          user#user_unassign
                          document_user_index GET    /documents/:document_id/user(.:format)                                 user#index
                                              POST   /documents/:document_id/user(.:format)                                 user#create
                            new_document_user GET    /documents/:document_id/user/new(.:format)                             user#new
                           edit_document_user GET    /documents/:document_id/user/:id/edit(.:format)                        user#edit
                                document_user GET    /documents/:document_id/user/:id(.:format)                             user#show
                                              PATCH  /documents/:document_id/user/:id(.:format)                             user#update
                                              PUT    /documents/:document_id/user/:id(.:format)                             user#update
                                              DELETE /documents/:document_id/user/:id(.:format)                             user#destroy
index_parent_attachments_document_attachments GET    /documents/:document_id/attachments/index_parent_attachments(.:format) attachments#index_parent_attachments
                         document_attachments GET    /documents/:document_id
```

Comment: I don't think your path definition is right.

Comment: document_user_user_unassign DELETE /documents/:document_id/user/:user_id/user_unassign(.:format)          user#user_unassign

Comment: What is the name of your user controller?

Comment: @user3461461 can you post your user controller code? Output of rake  routes should be users#create  insted of user#create

Comment: here: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20776515/users_controller.rb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `resources :documents` routes as below:

```
resources :documents do

  namespace :admin do       ## Added namespace
    resources :users do     ## updated resources as users(plural)
      delete 'user_unassign'
    end
  end                       ## end of :admin namespace 

  resources :attachments do    
    collection do
      get :index_parent_attachments
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer if it resolved your issue:)

Answer (score 2):

change  `resources :user`  to  `resources :users`

## Update

Change routes.rb file to

```
#routes.rb
resources :documents do

  resources :users do
     member do
       delete 'user_unassign'
     end
  end

end
```

and then in your view

```
<%= link_to 'unfollow', user_unassign_document_user_path, :method => 'delete' %>
```

Note  `user_unassign_document_user_path`  will give you a route like `localhost:3000/documents/:document_id/users/:id/user_unassign(.:format)`

Comment: can you share the output of running rake routes?

Comment: i cant paste all of them, i edited on top. The route involved is document_user_user_unassign DELETE /documents/:document_id/user/:user_id/user_unassign(.:format)          user#user_unassign